# Get a list of all cities in a country (or state), including latitude and longitude

Tags: graphhopper

How can I use GraphHopper to get a list of all cities in a country (or USA state)? For each city, I need a latitude and longitude.

(I presume the city's latitude and longitude would be the official middle of that city.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That process is called 'geocoding' and not done from GraphHopper. GraphHopper is only about finding the best way between 'raw' coordinates.

Geocoding itself is another research area and also complex ;). You can have a look at [nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) or [photon](https://github.com/komoot/photon/) or using the GraphHopper [Directions API](https://github.com/graphhopper/web-api/).

Another more simple solution for your situation could be to get the cities via OSM (parsing xml and find nodes having the tags place=city or town) or using [geonames](http://www.geonames.org/) or similar.